# why print screen takes default value

Tags: html, css

I need to print Date value in millimeter while i am printing default top value appear on screen but i also set padding and margin top value to 0. So top value differs from what i exactly need.ie., 31/7/14 will print on 12.7mm on from top.

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="margin:0mm;padding:0mm;">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top:12mm;">31/3/14</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you gave leaves the default padding in place for the body and table elements; throwing off your spacing. There is no need for the table elements. Using a "*" in the CSS matches all elements to remove margin and padding. A class can be used to set the div to 12mm off the top.

```
<html>
<style>
* {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
.top12mm {
   padding-top:12mm;
}
</style>
<body>
   <div class="top12mm">
       31/3/14
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```